# Obtaining tlmgr which wasn't installed with texlive in Scientific Linux

Tags: tlmgr

TeX Live was installed on my system as part of Scientific Linux 6. `tlmgr` wasn't installed. The rest of TeX Live was installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux/`. Where can I get TeX Live on its own?

Comment: have you tried the software repository of your OS?

Comment: Welcome! You can remove your OS's installation and install from upstream. Or you can stick with your OS's packages. However, don't try to do both as that will cause you endless trouble. You may not have `tlmgr` because you don't need it and are expected to stick to your OS's TeX Live packages. If you want to use `tlmgr` in its full glory, you'll want to install a dummy TL package for your OS and use upstream's TL installer.